# How to install "catdvi" in TeXLive?

Tags: texlive, ctan

I need to install [catdvi](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/catdvi), I am using the vanilla [TeXLive](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texlive) from CTAN. I have another option to install it is from the OS (i.e. Ubuntu) repository, but it will install another copy of OS specific TeX stack which I do not want.

[catdvi](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/catdvi) is not a latex macro/style file, it is an executable (like [xdvi](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/xdvi)). I can install xdvi using tlmgr, but not catdvi. Even my tlmgr gives detailed info on the xdvi status --

```
> tlmgr info xdvi
package:     xdvi
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   A DVI previewer for the X Window System.
longdesc:    The canonical previewer for use on Unix and other X-windows based systems. The distribution has been integrated with that of xdvik (no longer separately available), so that it will build with web2c "out of the box". In practice, it is usually distributed via Tex-live.
installed:   Yes
revision:    30339
sizes:       doc: 261k, run: 37k, bin: 1145k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 22.86
cat-date:    2013-05-08 11:16:41 +0200
cat-license: other-free
collection:  collection-basic
```

But tlmgr gives nothing on catdvi --

```
> tlmgr info catdvi
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: cannot find package catdvi
```

But both of them are in the [dviware](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware) directory.

How do I install it through TeXLive?

*Please also note that I have another option to directly download and compile the catdvi from the sourceforge [repository](http://catdvi.sourceforge.net/), but I do not want to do that.*

Comment: The trick is to install a dummy package which will convince the Ubuntu package manager that all of the dependencies are satisfied without using that package manager to install them. See the answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/39222.

Comment: @cfr: I have faked the tex installation for Ubuntu as described in that page. But when I tried to install catdvi, still the synaptic-package-manager tries to download and install tex-common, texlive-binaries and texlive-common. Although these packages are included in the "Provides:" entry of the equivs script. Any idea?

Comment: That's really a question about Ubuntu, I think, and you will likely get better help on their forums. Although I use this trick on two machines, neither uses a Debian-based distribution so if it doesn't work like it says on the tin, I think you have to go ask the tin-makers or at least other users of similar tins. Did you follow the links to Ubuntu/Debian/etc. resources from that page? There is also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137092/39222.